# Seleccionar una version diferente de angular al generar nuevo proyecto con angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Puede resultar una pregunta tonta, pero, el caso es que al generar un nuevo proyecto de angular con `ng new miproyecto` se instala por defecto la versión 6 de angular.

Puedo elegir que versión utilizar, por ejemplo si quiero instalar la versión 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu duda que tienes también la tienen muchos desarrolladores de Angular.

La respuesta es **No puedes sin cambiar de versión primero**.

Para cambiar la versión tienes que instalar una versión diferente del CLI especificando cual quieres usando el comando npm

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@version
```

donde `version` es una de las [versiones publicadas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli) del cli

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ten en cuenta que no es lo mismo generar componentes, servicios, ejecutar comandos, etc de un proyecto ya existente que crear uno nuevo. Si tienes un CLI global y uno local en un proyecto existente **el que se usará es el local**.

Este [fichero](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/schematics/angular/utility/latest-versions.ts) en github está en los [`schematics`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/packages/schematics) que son los que se usan para generar código y te dice las versiones que se usan en el último release.

```
export const latestVersions = {
  // These versions should be kept up to date with latest Angular peer dependencies.
  Angular: '~7.1.0',
  RxJs: '~6.3.3',
  ZoneJs: '~0.8.26',
  TypeScript: '~3.1.6',
  TsLib: '^1.9.0',
  // The versions below must be manually updated when making a new devkit release.
  DevkitBuildAngular: '~0.12.0-beta.1',
  DevkitBuildNgPackagr: '~0.12.0-beta.1',
};
```

Como ves es un fichero de código que se ejecuta cuando el CLI va a generar un proyecto nuevo y por lo tanto en tu instalación esos números están harcoded. Si vas a la instalación de tu `npm` global y buscas en este path `<npm_install_path>\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@schematics\angular\utility\` te encontrarás el mismo fichero. La ruta de instalación global de paquetes npm varía entre sistemas operativos por eso no la incluí.

La solución puede ser

- Instalar una versión menor del CLI global
- Generar tu aplicación
- Volver a actualizar el CLI global
- Ejecutar tu aplicación y los comandos usando un CLI local menor y un global mayor

Recuerda que el CLI ha ido evolucionando con el tiempo así que lo que te he dicho puede que no sea cierto para algunas versiones, sobre todo las primeras.

Comment: Y agregaría cuidado con angular-cli que fue la primera versión